# Show caption "No results" in VBA label when there's a null value in SQL

Tags: sql, vba

I would like to show the average rating of a movie from SQL database by typing in the Movie ID in VBA user form. The average rating will then be shown in textbox1. But if there's no rating for that Movie, "No results" caption will be shown in lb1. The code is work when there's data stored in the SQL database, but when there's no data founded (which AVG(MOV_RATING) is a null value), there's an error showing "Run-time error: could not see the value property. Type mismatch". Below is my code, can someone help me solve it? Many thanks.

```
Dim i as integer

    SQL = "SELECT AVG(MOV_RATING)" & _
     "FROM MOVIE" & _
     "WHERE MOV_ID = "' & label1.value & '""
    rs.Open SQL, cn

    With rs
    i = 0

    Do Until .EOF
    textbox1.Value = rs(0)
    i = i + 1
    .MoveNext

    Loop
    End With

    If i = 0 Then
    lb1.Caption = "No result"
    End If
```

Comment: I think your code would work as it is if you just add `On Error Resume Next` before the SQL SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check `rs.EOF`

```
Dim res

SQL = "SELECT AVG(MOV_RATING) FROM MOVIE" & _
      " WHERE MOV_ID = '" & label1.value & "'"
rs.Open SQL, cn

If Not rs.EOF Then
     res = rs(0).Value
     If IsNull(res) Then
         lb1.Caption = "No match"
     Else
         textbox1.Value = res
     End If
End If

rs.close
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't show "no match" when the value is null. How can I solve it?

Comment: OK time for some details - what database and driver are you using?  And which line has the error?